# ViewPager - How can I change how this looks? - android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that is using "tabs".  I have successfully implemented a design that uses these tabs in conjunction with a number of fragments.

however, I believe that these tabs look pretty ugly.  I want to customize how they appear! I prefer them to appear as plain text next to eachother with a "|" between them and underline the tab that the user is one.  Rather than the way they are currently designed which is each text per tab is separated evenly with a blue bar underneath it representing that it is selected.

I am not sure where to start.  how can I go about doing this?

Comment: start with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)

Comment: What are you using to display your tabs? Are you using Actionbar.Tab??  Some code would be nice

Comment: I would like the tabs to not appear at all!  Instead I would like the tab effect to be implemented as if it were plain text at the top of the child fragments.  So my "tabs" may look like this   "                 Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3                  "  - so all "tabs" would be much closer to each-other.  And the selected "tab" would be underlined directly instead of the big blue line that is traditional with tabs

Comment: @nkzk2 - I'm not looking to create images that appear on top of each fragment.  I am looking to redesign how the tabs appear to the user that will go beyond the abilities of adding an image to each tab

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **PagerSlidingTabStrip**

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/pager-sliding-tabstrip/

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

You can hook it up to your viewpager and customize your tabs in many different ways.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ill explore this, but initially it looks like its just the regular tabs that also has the ability for the user to scroll them.  Thanks

Comment: I have very good experience with PagerSlidingTabStrip. I love the feature `setShouldExpand` (Makes the tab fit the screen) and it have more options to customize your tabStrip (with colors, dividers etc) than pager-sliding-tabstrip (Have worked with both)